# Solving time dependent Schrodinger equation in matrix form

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, time, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

If we have a Hilbert space of $\mathbb{C}^3$ so that a wave function is a 3-component column vector
$$\psi_t=(\psi_1(t),\psi_2(t),\psi_3(t))$$
With Hamiltonian $H$ given by
$$H=\hbar\omega
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 0 \\
  2 & 0 & 2 \\
  0 & 2 & -1
 \end{pmatrix}$$
With
$$\psi_t(0)=(1,0,0)^T$$
So I proceeded to find the stationary states of $H$ by finding it's eigenvectors and eigenvalues. $H$ has eigenvalues and eigenvectors:
$$3\hbar\omega,0,-3\hbar\omega$$
$$\psi_+=\frac{1}{3}(2,2,1)^T,\psi_0=\frac{1}{3}(2,-1,-2)^T,\psi_-=\frac{1}{3}(1,-2,2)^T$$
Respectively.

Could anyone explain to me how to go from this to a general time dependent solution, and compute probabilities of location? I have only ever encountered $\Psi=\Psi(x,y,z,t)$ before, so I am extremely confused by this matrix format.

I would be extremely grateful for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general solution is $$\psi(t)=\sum_k c_k e^{-itE_k/\hbar}\psi_k$$ where the $\psi_k$ form a basis of eigenvectors with corresponding eigenvalues $E_k$, and the $c_k$ are constant.

You can match arbitrary initial conditions at $t=0$ by expanding the initial state in the eigenbasis; this will determine the valued for the $c_k$.

[Edit] To get the statistical interpretation:
The expectation of the Hermitian observable $A$ at time $t$ is given in the Schroedinger picture by $$\langle A\rangle_t:=\psi(t)^*A\psi(t).$$ Here it is assumed that $\psi(t)$ has norm 1. As the squared norm is preserved by the dynamics, this gives a well-defined expectation (i.e.,, the expectation of the identity matrix is 1 at all times).

Comment: Ok, good that's what I imagined to do, I wasn't sure. But more importantly how do you interpret this probabilistically in matrix form?

Comment: Does your $c=0$ mean $c(t=0)$ ?

Comment: The $c_k$ are constant, and a $t$ was missing in the exponent of the first formula. $c=0$ meant $t=0$. I corrected both errors; sorry.